# How to declare a byte array contains non-ascii characters without escape in python 3

Tags: python, unicode

Here is an example I wrote in python2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, struct

def pack(*s_list):
    return b"".join(struct.pack(">I", len(s)) + s for s in s_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.version)
    a = pack("α", "привет мир", "±")
    b = b"\x00\x00\x00\x02α\x00\x00\x00\x13привет мир\x00\x00\x00\x02±"
    print(a == b)
```

And the converted code for python 3,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, struct

def pack(*s_list):
    return b"".join(struct.pack(">I", len(b)) + b for b in (s.encode() for s in s_list))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.version)
    a = pack("α", "привет мир", "±")
    b = b"\x00\x00\x00\x02α" + "α".encode() + b"\x00\x00\x00\x13" + "привет мир".encode() + b"\x00\x00\x00\x02" + "±".encode()
    print(a == b)
```

I notice use `b = b"\x00\x00\x00\x02α\x00\x00\x00\x13привет мир\x00\x00\x00\x02±"` in python 3 will get an exception `SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.`,
so I had to escape them all or use many + like previous code.

Is there a better way to declare a byte array contains non-ascii character in python3?

Comment: You stated your problem well enough in the title: A *byte* array cannot contain *characters* :D The point is that in Python 3 *data* (byte arrays) and *text* (Unicode strings) are different things and shall not be mixed. The reason for that is that what you are trying to do there is likely to blow up in your face.

Comment: Characters like "α" isn't always be considered as a unicode character in all languages. I can declare "α" as a utf-8 byte array on c, c++ and python2. Also I can modify python3's source code to achieve this function but it will make the code only work on my machine.

Comment: That's the point, and it's a very good one. If you want UTF-8, then be explicit in doing so, by storing `α` in a string and converting into UTF-8.

Comment: Seems like an unnecessary limitation. The only difference between a literal string and a literal byte array should be that the literal string is parsed as some text encoding to unicode code points, while the byte array is literally everything between the quotes (after escape processing).

Comment: @Chinoto Correct. The source encoding shouldn't be involved in byte string literals. The bytes in the source file should be passed right along, just like in C or Python2. It's surprising how many languages get this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to do this, here is the example:

```
def to_bytes(string):
    result = b""
    need_eval = ""
    need_encode = ""
    for char in string:
        if char <= "\x7f":
            # if char is ascii, eval it with in b'...'
            if need_encode:
                result += need_encode.encode()
                need_encode = ""
            if char == "'":
                n = 0
                # get how many \ in the end of need_eval 
                for v in reversed(need_eval):
                    if v != "\\":
                        break
                    n += 1
                # if ' is not escaping
                if n % 2 == 0:
                    char = "\\'"
            need_eval += char
        else:
            # if char is non-ascii, encode it to utf-8
            if need_eval:
                result += ast.literal_eval("b'" + need_eval + "'")
                need_eval = ""
            need_encode += char
    result += need_encode.encode()
    result += ast.literal_eval("b'" + need_eval + "'")
    return result

b = to_bytes(r"\x00\x00\x00\x02α\x00\x00\x00\x13привет мир\x00\x00\x00\x02±")

print(repr(b))
print(to_bytes(r"±\xb1"))
print(to_bytes(r"\x90asdfg\\'\''\r\n\xff\u0001"))
```

Point is take the non-ascii part to encode and take other part to eval (because there no  string_escape encoding on python 3, I had to use ast.literal_eval).

The pain is it's not efficient.

Answer (score 11):

Another solution:

```
b = bytes("привет мир", 'utf-8')
```

Seems it is the better solution, since it has lesser copy operations.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work OK in Python 3.3.2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

b = bytearray("\x00\x00\x00\x02α\x00\x00\x00\x13привет мир"
              "\x00\x00\x00\x02±".encode())
```

Comment: It's interest, I didn't notice non-ascii characters can write in unicode then convert to utf-8. Unfortunately it wont work with all case, example: `"\x90".encode()` will be `b'\xc2\x90'`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the encoded byte representation of the characters, use that directly. Bytes and byte arrays do not contain characters at all - that's the whole point of the string/bytes distinction. They contain bytes that might represent characters in some particular encoding. I'd argue that that exception text is slightly misleading - the literal representation of a bytes object can only contain ASCII characters, but that doesn't mean the object itself contains ASCII characters any more than the object created by parsing the expression `[int("6")]` contains ASCII characters.

`'α'` encodes to `b'\xce\xb1'` in UTF-8, so you can build your bytes as `b=b"\x00\x00\x00\x02\xce\xb1\x00\x00\x00\x13"` etc.

If you do not know the appropriate bytes beforehand, using `encode()` to produce them is the best choice.

Comment: escape them is a good way if there no much non-acsii character, but I want something more clear and readable, still thanks your answer.

Comment: I don't know what other option you're going to have - either you have the bytes and should use them directly, or you don't have the bytes and should use `encode` to calculate them from the characters. You can encode longer strings than shown, or use something like `''.join()` rather than concatenation if that helps your readability, but ultimately you have to specify what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A working translation of your Python 2 function is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, struct

def pack(*s_list):
    # The original passed byte strings encoded in utf-8.
    # I convert the Python 3 Unicode strings to UTF-8 explicitly here.
    s_list = [s.encode('utf8') for s in s_list]
    return b"".join(struct.pack(">I", len(s)) + s for s in s_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.version)
    a = pack("α", "привет мир", "±")
    # In Python 2 Unicode characters in byte strings were implicitly in the encoding
    # of the file (utf8 above).  Python 3 must be explicit.
    b = "\x00\x00\x00\x02α\x00\x00\x00\x13привет мир\x00\x00\x00\x02±".encode('utf8')
    print(a == b)
```

Comment: While this code works in the specific example, note that hex codes in unicode strings do not always become the corresponding bytes. See user3085220's comment on martineau's answer.

Comment: @personal_cloud True.  Anything non-ASCII (>0x7F) would be encoded as multibyte.  There's not really a solution to that, since e.g. `'±'` == `'\xb1'` in a Unicode str.  Would the OP want the byte `B1` or the UTF-8 `C2 B1`?  OP would need to manually encode the Unicode characters as done in the original question example.

Comment: The OP wants the Python2 `str` behavior, which is unambiguous: each escape sequence becomes one byte. The OP's answer does this. (Sure, `'\xb1'` in a unicode string means something different, but the question is clearly about creating byte string literals.)

Comment: @personal_cloud The Python2 behavior **is** ambiguous.  In Python 2, `'±'` is a byte string and the byte content depends on the source encoding, e.g. `latin1` gives `B1` and `utf8` gives `C2 B1`.  In Python 3, `'±'.encode('utf8')` is completely unambiguous.

Comment: In Python 2, the output byte content depends only on the source byte content. Just like C (and most languages before JavaScript came along with something incompatible). Sure, you can change the source encoding, but that is a change to the source file. Where is the ambiguity?

Comment: @personal_cloud I guess you need to look at the number of questions where users are confused when their C strings don't contain what they thought because they copied the code off of some website and saved it in a different encoding.

Comment: *Users are confused when their C strings don't contain what they thought because they copied the code off of some website and saved it in a different encoding.* I understand that such mistakes occur. But if something broke when they changed their source code encoding, it's going to break in exactly the same way if they got the source code encoding right but changed the encoding of the input or output files. The language isn't going to save people from these situations.