# FTP_TLS 530 Login Incorrect with Python3 when password contains §

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ftp

I want to connect to my FTPS server using `python3`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from ftplib import FTP_TLS

host='my.url'
user='myuser'
passwd='password_containing_§'

ftp=FTP_TLS(url)
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.login(user,passwd)
```

But this gives an error whenever there is a `§` in the password.

```
*cmd* 'PASS ****************************************************************************************************'
*put* 'PASS ****************************************************************************************************\r\n'
*get* '530 Login incorrect.\n'
*resp* '530 Login incorrect.'
```

Tested with Python 3.5.2 and 3.7.6, same issue.

The exact same code and data **works well with Python2.7** (I just change the shebang to `python2`). Same login data also works well from Filezilla.

Can anybody  help out ?

---

I read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776615/python-ftplib-error-perm-530-login-authentication-failed) about sending the commands individually, but `ftp.sendcmd(...)` returns:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel
```

Comment: Try adding `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of your Python 2.7 code. In contrast with Python 2.7, Python 3 treats the string as unicode, so it may be it.

Comment: Then I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa7' in position 9`.

Comment: You can learn about this porting on [the official python page](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/pyporting.html#bytes-string-literals). You can treat the strings on Python 3 as in Python 2.7, by writing a `b` at the beggining of the literal: `passwd=b'mypasswd'`

Comment: But this gives `SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.`

Comment: I think you can work from here. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485845/how-to-declare-a-byte-array-contains-non-ascii-characters-without-escape-in-pyth).

Comment: Thanks for your help and the link, but it doesn't help. With `bytesarray()` I get Login incorrect, using `bytes()` I get `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly` and if casting with `str()` I get again Login incorrect :-(

Comment: @agastalver I think you're on the wrong track here anyways as this is not a bytestring, it's a simple unicode string and I still don't get what is wrong .

Comment: I was wrong too^^ it is a utf-8 string and I need to decode to unicode. See my answer. Thanks a lot for your help, sent me in the right direction !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```py
passwd = passwd.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629083/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-with-special-characters-in-python-to-print-prop))